# Does full rank matrix have a null space?

Tags: linear-algebra

The null space is defined as all vector that is set to null by matrix $A$, where $Ax = 0$.

If the matrix $A$ is full rank, does it mean that it has no null space?

Comment: What is $Ax$ for $x = 0$ and any matrix $A$?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An $m\times n$ matrix has *full rank* if it has the maximum rank possible. When $m=n$, of course, this means the matrix is invertible. When $m>n$, this means it has rank $n$ and the nullspace consists just of $0$. However, when $n>m$, this means that the matrix has rank $m$ and the nullspace will have dimension $n-m$.

Answer (score 5):

Any matrix always has a null space. An $m\times n$ full rank matrix with $m\geq n$ has only the trivial null space $\{0\}$. If $m<n$ then the matrix necessarily has larger null space, and if it also has full rank, the null space has dimension $n-m$.

Answer (score 2):

It's straight forward to check that the "null space",  $\{x:Ax=0\}$, is always a vector space.  As such it always contains the zero vector.  Indeed, any linear transformation takes zero to zero.

This is true whether or not the matrix has full rank.